# Make LaTeX directly recognize unicode symbol

Tags: symbols, unicode

I want to write the document in English, and copy-paste some text from online sources, where unicode symbols are usually used, for example:

```
$\frac{dω(τ)}{dτ}$
```

The letter tau is compilable in many places for example here, but not compliable on pdfLaTeX on Overleaf.

Is it possible to add a package to make things work?

Comment: overleaf is just hosting a standard texlive Greek letters would be defined by default if you use lualatex or xslatex  and `unicode-math`. but not otherwise. If they are defined "here" by which I assume you mean a local tex installation on your machine, the same definitions will work at overleaf, but you have not shown any example code

Comment: for pdflatex you could for example add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03C4}{\tau}` but show the definitions you are usiing on the document that you have that works.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to (or must) stay with pdflatex, the package "alphabeta" (part of [greek-fontenc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/greek-fontenc)) may help you:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\begin{document}
$\frac{dω(τ)}{dτ}$
\end{document}
```

Mind, that "alphabeta" and "unicode-math" are incompatible (the latter is to be preferred with Xe/LuaTeX).

Comment: Many thanks! I'll try it out

Answer (score 3):

In OpTeX, the Unicode Math is initialized when appropriate font family is selected by `\fontfam`. You needn't do more than:

```
\fontfam[lm]
$dω(τ)\over dτ$
\bye
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to add a package to make things work?

Such a package exists. Its name is [unicode-math](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math), and it's been around for several years already.

Observe that it's necessary to use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to process a document that loads the `unicode-math` package. To employ LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX in Overleaf, I suggest you proceed as follows: In an Overleaf project, begin by opening the "Menu" drop-down list. Then, under the "Settings" header, open the "Compiler" box. The default compiler is `pdfLaTeX`; choose either `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX` and proceed from there.

[image]

```
%% compile with either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\frac{dω(τ)}{dτ}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Mico, I changed to XeLatex, and I reloaded the page. However, it gives an error when compiling: "Package hyperref Error: Wrong driver option `pdftex',"

Comment: @dodo You seem to have `\usepackage[...,pdftex,...]{hyperref}`. Remove the wrong option. By the way, the `pdftex` option should ***never*** be used.

Comment: I do have \documentclass[pdftex .....

Comment: @dodo - Yes, by all means, do please omit the `pdftex` option.